# How to display the desired rows of two tables using a subquery?

Tags: sql

[image]

My subquery:

```
select studentName, Course.dataStart
from Student,
     Course
where Student.id in (select Course.id from Course);
```

I need a solution to this (above) subquery (not a join)

Why does the SQL subquery display one date for each name? (task: display the names of students from the Student table and the course start date from the Course table using a subquery)

With the help of Join, I get it as it should: (but I need to do it with a subquery)
[image]

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Why do you _need_ a subquery?

Comment: because it's my task to do it with a subquery and a join. (Join was successful for me, but the subquery displays the same start dates for each student name, instead of displaying the date for one student)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: `Student.id = Course.id` looks strange. I'd expect `Student.course_id = Course.id`, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using implicit join syntax, but really you should be using an explicit inner join:

```sql
SELECT s.studentName, c.dataStart
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Course c
    ON c.id = s.course_id;
```

If you really wanted to use the implicit join syntax, it should be something like this:

```sql
SELECT s.studentName, c.dataStart
FROM Student s, Course c
WHERE c.id = s.course_id;
```

But again, please use the first version as its syntax is considered the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply join :

```
SELECT S.studentName, C.dataStart
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Course C
ON C.id = S.course_id;
```

With Sub query:

```
Select studentName, (Select Course.dataStart from Course 
Where  Course.id = course_id)
From Student
```

Comment: @Dmitry Kolegov I think there is a join between `Course.id = Student.course_id` Let me know if I am incorrect.

Comment: Yes, your subquery option is exactly what I was trying to do, thanks. But you did it a little differently than my subquery style.

Comment: When I display your version - the name of the date column writes everything that is written in brackets, I still can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Can you please let me know that in which brackets the result is and how you want it ?

Comment: You already help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that Course.Id field is Student.Id (although it seems strange to me), I think the only way to get the results you want with a subquery would be using it in the SELECT clause:

```
select studentName, (SELECT Course.dataStart FROM Course WHERE Course.Id = Student.Id)
from Student
```

This would fail if you have more than 1 row in Course per Student, in that case you could use `(SELECT DISTINCT Course.dataStart...)`